# Can monsters use items with Cheat?

Tags: munchkin

We all know by now that Cheat only allows you to use items you would not usually be able to use.

Is there anything in the rules to stop you from giving Cheat to a Monster, and if not, is "being a Monster" a condition that Cheat circumvents?

Comment: Are you asking if you can equip a monster to yourself to gain combat bonus by using a cheat card? Or are you asking if you can give equipment to a monster with a cheat card? I predicated my answer based on the first scenario, but I will add info for the second as well.

Comment: So you want to give cheat to a monster to give an item to a monster? How do you plan to give cheat to a monster in the first place?

Comment: Cheat simply avoids an item's normal requirements (specific attribute/required hands/size) that would prevent you from using it. It doesn't change any other game rules.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The cheat! card specifically says:

"You may have and use any one **item** that would otherwise be against the rules"

However, monsters are not items (they are an entirely different type of card, falling under the door category) so they are not valid targets for the cheat! card.

If, instead, you're asking if Monsters can use items when you use the cheat card, I would still say no, as the card specifically says "**you** may have and use any one item" rather than something more broad, such as "Disregard all rules for this item"

Comment: I'm not really sure where the interpretation in the first paragraph came from (my question does explicitly say _give_ cheat _to_ a monster), but the second paragraph does answer my question really well; I definitely agree that 'you' is the key word here.

Comment: I guess I was reading it more as "use cheat on a monster" which sounds like trying to equip the monster. Some of the expansions enable similar behavior by "taming" monsters and such, so my brain was predisposed in that direction I suppose. Glad it still answered your question!

Comment: What about steeds?

Comment: @janw I believe steeds would be covered by the cheat! card, as I believe they are item cards rather than door cards. I believe you could therefore use two steeds or use a steed that would otherwise be unusable. Additionally, you could ask this as your own question if it has not already been asked

Comment: Yeah true about asking a own question. Steeds in M4 are door cards but are otherwise handled as (big) items. Some can even be sold. We always use allow cheats on them.